# using Cochran's theorem for sample variance where samples are not identical

Tags: statistics, random-variables

IS is possible to use Cochran's theorem to prove that the sample variance of normal variables is chi-square  in the case the variables are independent but not identical - they all have the same variance but each have different mean?